# Is it a good practice to use RowTest in a unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

NUnit and MbUnit has a RowTest attribute that allows you to sent different set of parameters into a single test.

```
[RowTest]
[Row(5, 10, 15)]
[Row(3.5, 2.7, 6.2)]
[Row(-5, 6, 1)]
public void AddTest(double firstNumber, double secondNumber, double result)
{
  Assert.AreEqual(result, firstNumber + secondNumber);
}
```

I used to be huge fan of this feature.  I used it everywhere.  However, lately I'm not sure if it's a very good idea to use RowTest in Unit Tests.  Here are more reasons:

A unit test must be very simple.  If there's a bug, you don't want to spent a lot of time to figure out what your test tests.  When you use multiple rows, each row has different sent set of parameter and tests something different.

Also I'm using [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/), that allows me to run my unit tests from my IDE, Visual Studio.  With TestDrivent.NET I cannot instruct to run a specific row, it will execute all the rows.  Therefore, when I debug I have to comment out all other rows and leave only the one I'm working with.

Here's an example how would write my tests today:

```
[Test]
public void Add_with_positive_whole_numbers()
{
   Assert.AreEqual(5, 10 + 15);
}

[Test]
public void Add_with_one_decimal_number()
{
   Assert.AreEqual(6.2, 3.5 + 2.7);
}

[Test]
public void Add_with_negative_number()
{
   Assert.AreEqual(1, -5 + 6);
}
```

Saying that I still occasionally use RowTest attribute but only when I believe that it's not going to slow me down when I need to work on this later.

Do you think it's a good idea to use this feature in a Unit test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** It's basically executing the same test over and over again with different inputs... saving you the trouble of repeating yourself for each distinct input combination.
Thus upholding the **'once and only once' or DRY principle**. So if you need to update this test you just update one test (vs multiple) tests.

Each Row should be a representative input from a distinct set - i.e. this input is different from all others w.r.t. this function's behavior.
The RowTest actually was a much-asked for feature for NUnit - having originated from MBUnit... I think Schlapsi wrote it as a NUnit extension which then got promoted to std distribution status. The NUnit GUI also groups all RowTests under one node in the GUI and shows which input failed/passed.. which is cool.

The minor disadvantage of the 'need to debug' is something I personally can live with.. It's after all commenting out a number of Row attributes temporarily (First of all most of the time I can eyeball the function once I find ScenarioX failed and solve it without needing a step-through) or conversely just copy the test out and pass it fixed (problematic) inputs temporarily

Comment: Also did I mention.. it gels well with my inherent laziness.